# eslint-plugin-vue vue/valid-v-model appears to warn using the rules in Vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vuejs3

I'm using Vue.js 3.
The following eslint-plugin-vue warning appears to warn using the rules in Vue.js 2.
`<MyComponent v-model:propName="foo"/>` This writing style is supported in Vue.js 3.
How to make it compatible with Vue.js 3?

```
<MyInputComponent
  v-model:value="state.value"
/>
// [vue/valid-v-model] 'v-model' directives require no argument. eslint-plugin-vue [7, 9]
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "vue": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.1.0",
    "vite": "^1.0.0-rc.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me - ignore the rule in `.eslintrc.js`:

```
  rules: {
    "vue/no-v-model-argument": "off",
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

Add these deps:

```sh
"@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
"@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.1",
"eslint": "^7.18.0",
```

install them:

```sh
npm i -D eslint @babel/core @babel/eslint-parser
```

change eslint.js

```js
parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
```

Comment: more details to this issue: https://babeljs.io/blog/2020/07/13/the-state-of-babel-eslint

Comment: Having these package doesn't help.